# Socket is not reading data

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying a simple Java program to send and receive data... Server is sending the data and Client receives that... But this generates Socket Exception : Connection Reset

This is my Server side code to sent Integer value...

```
try {
   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9089);

   Socket socket = server.accept();

   OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
   out.write(12);
   out.flush();
   System.out.println("Data Sent....");
   Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(Exception  e) {
   System.out.println("Server Error : " + e.toString());
}
```

This is my Client side code to receive that Int value...

```
try {
   Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9089);
   System.out.println("Connected ....");

   InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
   while(in.available()>0)
   {
      System.out.println("Unavailable...");
   }
   System.out.println("Received : " + in.read() );
   in.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Sender Error : " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: From server data sent message is shown... But on client side it goes in "while(in.available>0)" loop for few seconds and then SocketException is generated...

Comment: I would guess that the SocketException is thrown when your server side returns from the sleep. Does your server side terminate after the sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client code I think you have to change the condition of the while loop:

```
while(in.available()==0) {
    System.out.println("Unavailable...");
}
System.out.println("Received : " + in.read() );
in.close()
```

Comment: Just remove the test and block in the `read()`. Spin looping instead of blocking has nothing to recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

```
   while(in.available()>0)
   {
      System.out.println("Unavailable...");
   }
```

This doesn't make any sense. `available()` returns the number of bytes that *are* available. If the result is positive, data is *available,* not *unavailable.*

However this loop is completely pointless, and should just be removed completely. The following `read()` will block as long as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this this code

```
while(in.available()>0)
{
    System.out.println("Unavailable...");
}
```

would cause an endless loop if data was available.

try

```
while(in.available() == 0)
```